# AMQP-backed publish-subscribe channel and message conversion

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

We use an `<int-amqp:publish-subscribe-channel/>` as a kind of an event bus in our service-based application. The send method as well as the message handler are based on the `Message` class from spring-messaging (as of spring-integration 4.0 (+). Events are changes to entities that need to be picked up by other services.

The problem is: the spring-messaging `Message` class is treated as arbitrary object payload by spring-amqp as it is not recognized as a spring-amqp `Message`. This causes the following problems:

- default message format is serialized Java objects. spring-amqp does not only serialize our original payload object only, but also the wrapping spring-messaging `Message`, which is not compatible between Spring Framework 4.0 and 4.1
- configuring a message converter for JSON (`Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` to be exact) doesn't solve the problem, as it also converts the `Message` instance - which is spring-integration's `GenericMessage`, and that can't be instantiated from JSON as it lacks an appropriate constructor

We need to mix Spring versions, as we have services implemented with Grails 2.4 (based on Spring 4.0) and with current Spring Boot (relies on Spring 4.1).

Is there any way out of this, preferably an idiomatic spring-integration way? Is there maybe another abstraction instead or in addition to the `PublishSubscribeAmqpChannel`? Or any other means of message conversion that we could apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an amqp-backed channel, use an outbound-channel-adapter to send and an inbound-channel-adapter to receive.

The channel holds the entire message (serialized) whereas the adapters transport the payload as the message body and (optionally) map headers to/from amqp headers.

You will need to configure a fanout exchange for pub/sub (the channel will create one called `si.fanout.<channelName>` by default. You can then bind a queue for each recipient.

Comment: I will try that. Is this behavior of the PublishSubscribeChannel by design, or is this a bug? Should I open an issue?

Comment: It's by design (the same technique is used in the JMS-backed channel), but I think we __could__ make an improvement by adding an option to use the header mapping technique instead of sending the whole message. However, the persistence-backed channels are designed for message persistence within an application (to avoid message loss), not for distributing messages to disparate systems/applications; that's what the channel adapters are designed for.

Comment: I understand the concept for persistence-backed channels. It is pretty counter-intuitive (at least to me) that AMQP-backed (same for JMS for that matter) are regarded as _persistence_-backed rather than _remote-transport_-backed. IMHO this should be clearly pointed out in the reference guide, where the description of the PublishSubscribeAMQPChannel is scarce at best.